# Map Return with no other input to an alias

Tags: bash, zsh, line-editor

I would like to use <kbd>Return</kbd> with no other input to run an aliased command in the shell. Is this possible in Bash or Zsh?

In other words, when I enter an empty command line, I want to run one specific command. Other command lines should of course not be affected.

```
$ ls <Return>
→ run ls
$ <Return>
→ run my aliased command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but with `zsh`:

```
accept-line() {: "${BUFFER:="my-aliased-command"}"; zle ".$WIDGET"}
zle -N accept-line
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty buffer would run `my-aliased-command`

That's redefining the `accept-line` widget as a function. In `zle` (zsh line editor) widgets, `$BUFFER` contains the content of the command line so far. So here we're setting it to `my-aliased-command` if it was previously empty, and then run the builtin `accept-line` widget (`.accept-line`).

Note that means that the `my-aliased-command` will be added to the command history.

If you don't want that, another approach could be:

```
accept-line() {
  if [[ -z $BUFFER ]]; then
    zle -I
    my-aliased-command
  else
    zle ".$WIDGET"
  fi
}
zle -N accept-line
```

If `$BUFFER` is empty, invalidate the prompt (no need to do that if the command outputs nothing) and run the `my-aliased-command`. Run the builtin `accept-line` otherwise.

Comment: Cool. Any chance you could say something about how that works or provide a link to somewhere I can read about that syntax?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in bash 4, but more cumbersome than [in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166266). You need to define a function to test if the command line is empty; the command line is in the variable `READLINE_LINE`. It's easier to use this function to insert the desired command for empty lines, rather than arrange to run the command silently. After running this function, inject a key sequence which is bound to the default mapping for <kbd>Return</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is normally a synonym. Untested code.

```
insert_default_command_if_empty () {
  if [[ -z $READLINE_LINE ]]; then READLINE_LINE='ls -l'; fi
}
bind '"\e[z1~": insert_default_command_if_empty'
bind '"\C-m": "\e[z1~\C-j"'
```